# c++ copy assignment and move assignment are not being called

Tags: c++, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

I am trying to implement copy and move assignments, but I don't understand how should I use them. I have read the following topic 
[When did copy assignment operator called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154814/when-did-copy-assignment-operator-called) 
But it did not work for me.

**Class:**

```
class Directory{

    string name;
public:
        Directory(string name):name(name) {

        }
        ~Directory() {
            cout << "Deleting was called" <<endl;

            }

        Directory& operator=(Directory& other){
            cout << "cp assigment" <<endl;
            return *this;
        }
        Directory& operator=(Directory&& other){
            cout << "move assigment" <<endl;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{

    Directory* dir = new Directory("alex");
    Directory* dir2;
    dir = dir2;

    cout<<"done"<<endl;
};
```

I would like to know when the copy assignment and move assignment are called. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The assignment is done for pointers (`Directory*`) in your case. Remove the `*`s and the `new` and it will work.

Comment: You are working with pointers, how would you expect copy would be called??

Comment: `dir = dir2;` invokes built-in pointer copy assignment operator, not your class copy assignment operator.

Comment: Btw. `dir2` is uninitialized. Hence, after `dir = dir2;` `dir` has the same value and the pointer to the `new`ed instance is lost. This is a memory leak.

Comment: I have removed the new and *s. But now there are a runtime error - error: use of deleted function ‘Directory::Directory(const Directory&)’
         Directory dir =  Directory("alex");
                                          ^

Comment: Use of deleted function: You have to define a copy constructor. I'm always not quite sure when the copy constructor is auto-defined when not. But actually it is always better to follow the [rule of 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). (Hence, I don't know because I don't need to know.)

Comment: It might feel tedious to always write "all 5". So, it might be interesting to know about: `Directory() = default;` (forces the auto-creation of default constructor), `Directory(const Directory&) = default;` (forces the auto-creation of default copy constructor) and so on.

Comment: ...and to prevent unintended copying of class instances (when this shouldn't happen) a `Directory(const Directory&) = delete;` can be used to force the "not-auto-creation" of a default copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my first comment, I recommended to remove all `*`s and the `new`.

Hence the main function becomes:

```
int main()
{
  Directory dir = Directory("alex");
  Directory dir2;
  dir2 = dir; // <-- fixed, original was: dir = dir2;

  cout<<"done"<<endl;
  return 0; // <-- fixed, return is strictly recommended for every non-void function
}
```

Compiling...

**Error**: Something is wrong in `Directory dir = Directory("alex");` (usage of deleted copy constructor).

The copy-constructor is used to initialize `dir` with the temporary instance created by `Directory("alex")`.

This is easy to change:

```
int main()
{
  Directory dir("alex"); // <-- fixed: direct construction
  Directory dir2;
  dir2 = dir;

  cout<<"done"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling...

**Error**: Something is wrong in `Directory dir2;`.

A yepp. You defined constructor `Directory(string name);`. This suppresses the auto-creation of the default constructor which would be needed here.

We either could add the default constructor to `class Directory`:

```
  Directory() = default;
```

or we can improve the existing non-default constructor so that it can be used as default constructor as well:

```
  Directory(string name = string()): name(name) { }
```

The whole source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Directory{

    string name;
public:
        Directory(string name = string()):name(name) {

        }
        ~Directory() {
            cout << "Deleting was called" <<endl;

            }

        Directory& operator=(Directory& other){
            cout << "cp assigment" <<endl;
            return *this;
        }
        Directory& operator=(Directory&& other){
            cout << "move assigment" <<endl;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main() {
    //Directory dir = Directory("alex");
    Directory dir("alex");
    Directory dir2;
    dir2 = dir;

    cout<<"done"<<endl;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it compiles and works.

Output:

```
cp assigment
done
Deleting was called
Deleting was called
```

You can see it live on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/WiM0yD).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Directory{
public:
       string name;

        Directory() {
            cout << "Constructor 1 was called" <<endl;            
        }

        Directory(string name):name(name) {
            cout << "Constructor 2 was called" <<endl;            
        }

        ~Directory() {
            cout << "Deleting was called" <<endl;
        }

        Directory(const Directory& other){
            cout << "cp cons" <<endl;
        }

        Directory& operator=(const Directory& other){
            cout << "cp assigment" <<endl;
            return *this;
        }

        Directory& operator=(Directory&& other){
            cout << "move assigment" <<endl;
            return *this;
        }
};


int main()
{

    Directory dir = Directory("alex");
    Directory dir2;
    dir2 = dir;

    cout << "done " << dir.name << dir2.name << endl;
};
```

I changed the code so it doesn't use pointers, add extra constructors (notice the copy constructor) and added some extra printing.

I get this output:

```
Constructor 2 was called
Constructor 1 was called
cp assigment
done alex
Deleting was called
Deleting was called
```

From this you can see that your copy assignment is incorrect as it still prints "alex" but I guess you are only interested in the function being called and not what they do.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It really works. I am trying to learn from this example. I don't understand why your code works, and my is not working. The main part is the same, after an edit.

Comment: @AlexLavriv - did you add a copy constructor like I did?

Comment: @AlexLavriv - This link may be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945598/4386427

Comment: I have added it now. And it works. But it does not use it. For some reason the move assignment requires the copy constructor to be presented. It's a really strange behavior.

Comment: @AlexLavriv - there is no move assignment involved. It's an optimization eliding the temporary (i.e. `Directory("alex");`).